# UIPageController - Move background image behind the UIPageControl

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller, uipagecontrol

I have created an app using UIPageController using this tutorial: http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-storyboard-tutorial/

As you can see on the screenshot below, there is a white background behind the UIPageControl at the bottom. I want to move the blue background image (it will be a custom image later, just using a blue image now) down so the UIPageControl is in the front, see the other image for how I want it to be.

**How it is now:**

[image]
**How i want it to be:**

[image]

Comment: What are the frame sizes for the image and the view controller? Have you set constraints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to solve the same problem recently.

You can customize the bottom, UIPageControl view's background and indicator "dots" with the following:

```
UIPageControl *pageControl = [UIPageControl appearance];
[pageControl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"PageControlBottom"]]];
[pageControl setPageIndicatorTintColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
[pageControl setCurrentPageIndicatorTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

Unfortunately, [pageControl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]]; doesn't work. So you'll have to set a solid UIPageControl background color or you'll have to cut out the bottom portion of your view's image  and set it as the background image as I've done above.